# Teamviewer - How to make it lock the computer after session is closed

Tags: windows, teamviewer

Where is the option so that whenever a remote connection is closed windows get locked to the login screen? Also, is it possible to is it like that but unlock automatically (ie enter the windows password) when I make a new connection?

thanks

Answer (score 3):

Menu `Actions` > `Lock computer` > `Lock on session end`

And no, it is not possible to automatically login when connecting.

Comment: Is this permanent??? I want something permanent whoever connect to that computer. Why I've that option set, then I disconnect, go physically to that somputer and its unlocked, anyone can access it??? Also, it seams that either the program is bugged or I am missing something, because I've set blank screen and disable input and it doesnt stay that way, sometimes I connect again is doesnt do it...

Comment: If you create a teamviewer account, and you add a computer to your contact list, you can specify these options too. This is the way teamviewer intended this to be used, but normally it should remember the settings unless someone else connects to the same computer with different settings.

Comment: I did specify in the account, exactly... and it's not staying that way. The lock on session end is not working... sometimes it works sometimes not... mostly not... and the option is checked.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. This is the way to do it, but if it doesn't always work, then you'll have to find out why it doesn't always work. I can't help you with that unfortunately.

Comment: @RukinoJinsen - If you have an answer you should provide one, not modify an existing answer, so it says the complete opposite of what the author said.

Answer (score 1):

@Ramhound - Sorry if I had to edit something from the first answer, it is because I can't post a comment yet to other people's question or answer in Superuser ,only to my own questions & actually the answer is indeed partially correct (1st sentence correct & 2nd sentence incorrect) so I thought maybe I could just modify it to rectify it. I can somehow able to post a real answer but I'm tired of making another one 'cause it disagrees with the 2nd sentence of the 1st answer. That would be confusing to have 2 opposing answers, you know.

As for the real answer, it is a yes that one can locked the computer right after every end of remote connection using TeamViewer (1st sentence of the 1st answer). And it is definitely a yes, not no, that one can remotely input password at the locked screen while in remote session with TeamViewer. You can even start TeamViewer right after the startup of the computer even if you're not still logged on as a user by making sure you always keep yourself signed in on TeamViewer then add TeamViewer program as a basic task in Task Scheduler in your computer.

Here's how to add TeamViewer program as a basic task in Task Scheduler (Windows 7):

(Important note: The users must belong to the admin group which have admin rights.)

1. Go to 'Start Menu' -> 'All Programs' -> 'Accessories' -> 'System tools' -> 'Task Scheduler' or alternatively go to 'Control Panel' -> 'System and Security' -> 'Administrative Tools' -> 'Task Scheduler'. You can just also search for it. Click it from the search results right after you found it.
2. On the Task Scheduler window, locate the 'Create Basic Task...' button. Click it.
3. Name your task and add description (optional). When done, tap 'Next'.
4. Specify the time period or event you want your task to be executed. Choose "When the computer starts". Click 'Next' again.
5. Assign an action the task will perform. Choose "Start a program". Then click 'Next' again.
6. Click the 'Browse...' button then locate "TeamViewer.exe" to add it as a Program/script. "Add arguments" and "Start in" are optional. Click 'Next' again.
7. Check the "Open the Properties dialog for this task when I click Finish". Click 'Finish' if you're done with the setup.
8. On the "Properties dialog" in "General" tab, check the "Run whether user is logged on or not". Click "Ok".
9. Done! Run TeamViewer app or application from your wireless device or client computer. Make sure you kept signed in always with the same TeamViewer account in both wireless/computer devices. Also make sure the TeamViewer ID of the app from the wireless device is already added to the "Whitelist" list of the TeamViewer application in your computer.

There are also programs or apps like Shutdown Start Remote app and executable program that startup / shutdown the computer or even wake it up from sleep mode and are downloadable to the computer or to wireless devices.

Here's how to set up "Shutdown Start Remote" app and application which can be installed only to an android device & computer:

1. In both of your android device and computer, go to your browser and type "www.android-powerpoint.com/shutdown" in the address box. Press 'Enter'.
2. Download, from the site, the computer application for the computer and the android app for your android device. Install them separately based on the compatibility of the applications to each device.
3. From the computer, make the computer application auto-start at startup by creating a shortcut for the application then add it to the startup folder. It is also possible to hide the application window after your computer booted, so you don't need to minimize it, by opening first the shortcut's properties then add the "hide" word after the "... .jar" file divided by a space at the file location's name. Tap 'Apply' then click 'Ok'.
4. From the android device, open the app then it will automatically detect the computer, if the computer application is already running, based on the computer's ip address.
5. Done! Now you can turn the computer on/off or make it sleep/wake up remotely with the use of the app on the android device.

(Important note: For it to work, you need to make sure the computer is always plugged in to its power supply and the internet or Wi-Fi is always available and present in all of your devices.)

I've already uploaded a video on how to do all of these:
Here's [a link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PM-s5WkeZlc) on my Youtube channel. I recommend you to watch it on its desktop view because there are annotations that will guide you step-by-step on how to make it happen.

From all of these, you can make your computer remotely dependent and almost completely controllable by a remote device or computer. Hope that clarifies all of you who have already read this and even to those who will read this question & answer post in the future. Thank you!

Comment: Since I think its not possible, would you mind to edit your post and add how you can make it happen that teamviewer automatically enters this password? I couldn't figure out how to do this and I am gladly wrong and learn something new.

Comment: Well, I'm still new to Superuser online community but I based myself on what I have experienced before. I'm also somewhat frustrated too when I'm still new on using the TeamViewer program and app to our family's computer and my tablet because I cant find a solution to remotely input password & logon as a user right after the startup of the PC. Until I found out a Windows 7 service component called 'Task Scheduler'. Task Scheduler can make programs start and run right after the startup of the computer. You still have to input PW from the app then to the lock screen but remotely from TeamViewer.

Comment: you first said you were able to make teamviewer enter the password of the lock screen, your answer says so, and now your comment says otherwise...

Comment: But SuperUser is a Q&A site. If someone asks a question, they want an answer and know how to accomplish it. You basically just said: yes its possible, without actually adding how. Without this information the answer is basically useless. So please edit your answer and include the "how-to" where applicable.

Comment: You can use an external image hosting service and link to the images. Someone with reputation will then edit in the images for you. :)